# How to invoke the screen saver in Windows in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, managed, screensaver

I'd like to invoke the user's screen saver if such is defined, in a Windows environment.

I know it can be done using pure C++ code (and then the wrapping in C# is pretty simple), as suggested [here](http://bobmoore.mvps.org/Win32/w32tip22.htm).

Still, for curiosity, I'd like to know if such task can be accomplished by purely managed code using the dot net framework (version 2.0 and above), without p/invoke and without visiting the C++ side (which, in turn, can use windows API pretty easily).

Comment: You can call the Windows API from within C# very easily as well.

Comment: duplicate (has the answer you are looking for): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267728/launch-system-screensaver-from-c-windows-form

Comment: Not a dupe - the question is how to do it without p/invoke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've an idea, I'm not sure how consistently this would work, so you'd need to research a bit I think, but hopefully it's enough to get you started.

A screen saver is just an executable, and the registry stores the location of this executable in `HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\SCRNSAVE.EXE`

On my copy of Vista, this worked for me:

```
RegistryKey screenSaverKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Control Panel\Desktop");
if (screenSaverKey != null)
{
    string screenSaverFilePath = screenSaverKey.GetValue("SCRNSAVE.EXE", string.Empty).ToString();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(screenSaverFilePath) && File.Exists(screenSaverFilePath))
    {
        Process screenSaverProcess = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(screenSaverFilePath, "/s"));  // "/s" for full-screen mode
        screenSaverProcess.WaitForExit();  // Wait for the screensaver to be dismissed by the user
    }
}
```

Comment: That may work, but Windows has built in mechanisms that trigger the screensaver. You should use these, also it's easier to implement than doing it manually.

Answer (score 1):

I think having a .Net library function that does this is highly unlikely - I'm not aware of any.  A quick search returned this Code Project [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ScreenSaverControl.aspx) which contains an example of a managed wrapper which you mentioned in your question.

P/invoke exists so that you're able to access OS-specific features, of which screen savers are an example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can use completely managed code to do this.

This uses Windows API but is still very simple: [Launch System Screensaver from C# Windows Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267728/launch-system-screensaver-from-c-windows-form)

Answer (score 0):

Working on any version of windows...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HQ.Util.Unmanaged
{
    public class ScreenSaverHelper
    {
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetDesktopWindow")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();

        // Signatures for unmanaged calls
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(int uAction, int uParam, ref int lpvParam, int flags);

        // Constants
        private const int SPI_GETSCREENSAVERACTIVE = 16;
        private const int SPI_SETSCREENSAVERACTIVE = 17;
        private const int SPI_GETSCREENSAVERTIMEOUT = 14;
        private const int SPI_SETSCREENSAVERTIMEOUT = 15;
        private const int SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING = 114;
        private const int SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 2;

        private const uint DESKTOP_WRITEOBJECTS = 0x0080;
        private const uint DESKTOP_READOBJECTS = 0x0001;
        private const int WM_CLOSE = 16;

        public const uint WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x112;
        public const uint SC_SCREENSAVE = 0xF140;
        public enum SpecialHandles
        {
            HWND_DESKTOP = 0x0,
            HWND_BROADCAST = 0xFFFF
        }
        public static void TurnScreenSaver(bool turnOn = true)
        {
            // Does not work on Windows 7
            // int nullVar = 0;
            // SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETSCREENSAVERACTIVE, 1, ref nullVar, SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);

            // Does not work on Windows 7, can't broadcast. Also not needed.
            // SendMessage(new IntPtr((int) SpecialHandles.HWND_BROADCAST), WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_SCREENSAVE, 0);

            SendMessage(GetDesktopWindow(), WM_SYSCOMMAND, (IntPtr)SC_SCREENSAVE, (IntPtr)0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Confirmed, it does work on win10.