# WPF: Create your own screen-saver if your running application is 'idle'

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, screensaver

Is there a way to create a window (similar to a screen-saver) that will be displayed once your running application is not 'interacting' (or being idle) with the user, meaning to say, no mouse movements happening on the application.

Some of my friends suggested to use a Timer for this one. Any suggestion for a good head start? Thanks.

Comment: No mouse movement, does not always mean the user is idle, some people prefer to use the keyboard. You should be checking for key presses as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your looking to create your own screensaver just create another form.  Remove the border from the form.  Make it the top most and start maximized.  Then you just paint the control to do whatever you want.

Then wire up the form to check if the mouse moves or a key is pressed.  You'll need to create a timer that will determine if the screensaver should be shown.

Answer (score 1):

This might help: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/csharpscreensaver.aspx.

There's a similar question on StackOverflow here: [How to invoke the screen saver in Windows in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927843/how-to-invoke-the-screen-saver-in-windows-in-c).

Comment: I was actually looking for 'creating a window similar to a screen-saver'. Thanks for the answer though.