# How to get the screen timeout event in windows

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-10-desktop, windows-screensaver

I'm new to windows desktop application development and I'm working on a project in that I need to show images that are downloaded from the internet once the screen is timed out as like a screensaver. I have gone through the System events from the below link but I didn't get anything useful.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents?view=net-5.0
Can anyone suggest to me how to achieve my requirement?

I'm using .net for development and I'm using windows forms.

Comment: When a ScreenSaver is run, you get, in WndProc,  a [WM_SYSCOMMAND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-syscommand) message, with wParam set to `SC_SCREENSAVE` (`m.WParam.ToInt64() & 0xfff0) == SC_SCREENSAVE`).  -- Then you can [terminate the ScreenSaver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66212525/7444103) and activate your own app. -- Or, as suggested, write a ScreenSaver directly (it's a ~standard executable).

Comment: See also: [Handling Screen Savers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/lwef/screen-saver-library)