# Screen Saver hack project gone bad user32.dll screensaver timeout issue

Tags: c#, screensaver, notifyicon

Very simple project, Win7, VS2012, Winforms.

**Popup a warning window 1 minute before a screensaver engages to inform the user they will be locked out soon.**

However everytime I pop the window using the code below, the screensaver timeout is reset and my 1 minute turns into .  I'm reading user32.dll "static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO plii);" and the time there reflects the last time I moved the mouse, so at 0 minutes it equals .

I have a form with a notify icon that sits in the task bar.  On load I call this.Hide() and notifyIcon1.Visible = true.  When one minute hits I run either of the following that resets the timer.

```
void Maximize()
{
    this.TopMost = false;
    this.Show();
    this.TopMost = true;
}
```

OR

```
void Maximize()
{
    this.TopMost = false;
    this.Show();
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    this.TopMost = true;
    this.Activate();
    this.Focus();
}
```

What do you think, windows bug?

Comment: I removed everything except this.windowstate = Formwindowstate.Normal and still I get a screensaver timeout reset.  Quite frustrating.  I can't imagine every time I get an chat message on google talk that the screen saver resets.

Comment: Had to manually code the locking of the system using this article, what a bust.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430108/how-to-turn-screensaver-on-windows-7-by-a-code-in-cmd